# Is thin kind of implementation safe(reimplement max with auto and type_traits)

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template<typename T, typename U>
struct promote
{
  private:
    typedef typename std::conditional<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)), T, U>::type Bigger;
    typedef typename std::add_const<Bigger>::type BConst;

  public:
    //because mingw4.6.2 do not implement std::add_reference
    typedef typename boost::add_reference<BConst>::type type;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
auto max(T const &a, U const &b)->typename promote<T, U>::type
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::cout<<max(3, 4.5)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<max(4.5, 3)<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

std::max of mingw4.6.2

```
template<typename T>
inline T const& max(T const &a, T const &b)
{
  return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

This will give me warning messages

main.cpp:27:24: warning: returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]

main.cpp:27:24: warning: returning reference to temporary [enabled by default]

Compiler is migw4.6.2, OS is win7 64bits

second version, only support scalar type

```
template<typename T, typename U>
struct promote
{
   typedef typename std::conditional<(sizeof(T) > sizeof(U)), T, U>::type type;

};

template<typename T, typename U>
inline typename promote<T, U>::type max(T a, U b)
{
  static_assert(std::is_scalar<T>::value, "inhomogeneous max only support scalar type");
  static_assert(std::is_scalar<U>::value, "inhomogeneous max only support scalar type");

  return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

The other solution are using SFINAE and boost::mpl to do some "overload".
I think I would just explicitly name the type of std::max in the real case

Comment: Doesn't the compiler warning answer your question?

Comment: Complete sources please. No need to strip #include directives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not safe. That's exactly what the compiler warns you about. You return reference to a temporary value (4.5 in this case). If you assign the result to something like `int &x = max(3, 4,5);`, `x` will become a dangling reference immediately after this line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `max()` in general is that you want it to do one of two things:

1. Select the maximum of homogenous values and return a reference to this value.
2. Select the maximum of inhomogenous values and return the result value converted to the most general type.

Returning a reference in the inhomogenous case does not work because a reference to a temporary is returned which will cease to exist before the call of the function can take hold of it. Returning a value in the homogenous case is probably not desirable.

Comment: Thanks, I pass in homogenous type, the result is same as std::max, but inhomogenous type would give me warning message.